# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 / Insufficent system resources (66192371)

Tags: vb.net, dbf, oledbdataadapter

I'm receiving Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 / Insufficent system resources (66192371) everytime I try to read a DBF file my connection string looks as follows:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\PointOfSale****;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=**;Password=**;

My query: SELECT DESCRIPT, REF_NO FROM TABLE.DBF

My program executes correctly on many PCs but once I deploy this on customer environment I'm having described issue.

Any comment at this moment will be very helpful, thanks in advance!

Comment: compare the OS versions and SP levels between ones it works on vs those it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

Is the table really a dbase table or FoxPro table... if FoxPro, I would download Microsoft's VFP OleDbProvider and use that.

As for your connection.  You have it somewhat masked out with ****.  Just to clarify the Data Source should only point to the PATH where the actual .dbf files reside and NOT mention the entire path plus the .dbf file.  Once the connection is made to the PATH, you should be able to select from any table in that folder without the explicit .dbf reference in your query, such as

```
select field1, field2 from YourTable
```

or even

```
select 
      t1.field1,
      t1.field2,
      t2.fieldX,
      t2.fieldY
   from
      YourTable t1
         JOIN AnotherTable t2
            on t1.SomeKey = t2.MatchingKey
```

Comment: Thank you! yes I already changed to VFPOLEDBLib but I'm still getting this issue, DB is mapped to another repository on customer's enviroment, maybe I need to handle this but I'm not sure, error displayed is not explicit... Douh!

Comment: @user3516084, can you show your final VFPOleDb Connection string (less any user/password.

Comment: Of course, here you have... thanks in advance! Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=" + db_path + ";Collating Sequence=general;"

Comment: @user3516084, can you please re-edit your original post, and paste your actual code for the connection, command object and execute.  Use the curly brackets to "format" the code for readability.  Unless the database (.dbf) file is not really a .dbf, or is part of a .dbc located in another physical folder giving you problems, that may be a part of it...

Comment: thanks! Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=C:\PointOfSale\installed;Collating Sequence=general;"